# How to run the ns2mobility.tcl file that generated by SUMO – Simulation of Urban MObility?

Tags: ns2, sumo

When I tried to run the `ns ns2mobility.tcl` on  Ubuntu 18.04, I got this message :

> can't read "node_(0)": no such variable
>
> while executing
>
> "$node_(0) set X_ 1508.89"
>
> (file "ns2mobility.tcl" line 1)

The `ns2mobility.tcl` contains the following:

```
$node_(0) set X_ 1508.89
$node_(0) set Y_ 767.16
$node_(0) set Z_ 0
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1508.89 767.16 0.00"
$ns_ at 1.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1507.78 766.24 1.44"
$ns_ at 2.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1505.37 764.25 3.12"
$ns_ at 3.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1501.0 760.63 5.66"
$ns_ at 4.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1495.11 755.76 7.62"
$ns_ at 5.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1487.78 749.77 9.45"
$ns_ at 6.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1478.55 742.12 11.99"
$ns_ at 7.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1468.05 733.42 13.63"
$ns_ at 8.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1456.95 724.24 14.40"
$ns_ at 9.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1445.98 715.51 14.01"
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1435.15 707.01 13.75"
$ns_ at 11.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1423.57 697.92 14.72"
$ns_ at 12.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1412.67 689.36 13.85"
$ns_ at 13.0 "$node_(0) setdest 1401.56 680.64 14.12"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SUMO movement file (ns2mobility.tcl) is meant to be used in an ns2 "vanet simulation file.tcl" :

After the node creation in the simulation file, the sumo file is called with `source ns2mobility.tcl`. I.e. 1) The file ns2mobility.tcl is not a simulation. Is the movement settings only. 2) "$node_(0) set X ..." , and $ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(0) setdest ..." doesn't work untill some nodes are defined.

See Vanet simulation examples : Vanet-examples-09.18.tar.gz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wcDPDk68e6OPsUBaE_yC7whaAqUmTWf3/view?usp=sharing ... **and** → http://neo.lcc.uma.es/staff/jamal/vanet/index.html%3Fq=node%252F11.html

Comment: Could you please tell me how to generate the `source ns2mobility.tcl`

Comment: `source` means "call the file / read the file". Nothing to be done. You already have the file = ns2mobility.tcl

Comment: I already changed the source to `source ns2mobility.tcl` as it is in this video https://youtu.be/48N_BCeDFkI?t=1668 but it gives an error and the .nam is empty.

Comment: The essential information is missing : **Which simulation file are you using** ? .... A good place to start is with e.g. the basic `guindy.tcl` : Test the file as is → `$ ns  guindy.tcl` .....  And then make your changes. .... But you won't get much traffic with only one "car" moving (ns2mobility.tcl).

Comment: I will try it,  In the question ,  I only show an example only of the data.

Comment: it works after I follow the instruction of this video https://youtu.be/48N_BCeDFkI?t=1578 . is it possible to run the `ns2mobility.tcl` in `ns3` without the information that is in `guindy.tcl`